# Exp:resso Store - Change checkout button from input to href

Tags: expresso-store

I am using a custom button which uses a href and I was wondering if it is possible to change the input submit checkout button from using an input to using a href?

So from something like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

to

```
<a href="#">Add to Cart</a>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, because an `<a>` element doesn't submit the form.

If you don't like `<input type="submit">`, you can also use `<input type="image">` or a `<button>` element, and you are free to style all of these however you like using CSS.

Comment: You can still style the submit button the same way as an `<a>` tag.